# NAnt ignoring property in included build file

Tags: nant

I'm trying to make my project build file include a local build file, to allow for some customization for each developer, without having to keep exclulding the build file from version control commits etc.

But NAnt keeps ignoring the properties in my included build file, and not overwriting the properties set in the global build file.

For demo purposes this short build file behaves the same:

```
<project name="FooProject" default="showme" basedir="." >
<description>Foo</description>
<!-- Overwrite this property in local.build -->
<property name="database.connectionstring" overwrite="true" readonly="false" value="foo" />

<include buildfile="local.build" failonerror="true" verbose="true" />

<target name="showme" description="Show connectionstring variable">
    <echo message="Connectionstring: ${database.connectionstring}" />
</target>
</project>
```

-and my local.build file looks like this:

```
<property name="database.connectionstring" value="bar" />
```

The expected output when running NAnt with this build file is "Connectionstring: bar", but the resulit is "Connectionstring: foo", no matter which combination of readonly and overwrite I try.

It does fail if I rename the file to something else, so NAnt is aware of the included file.

NAnt is v0.91 alpha.

Am I overlooking something or is NAnt not supposed to work like I expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you should still wrap the contents of the included build file inside a project-element. Like so:

```
<project>
<property name="database.connectionstring" value="bar" />
</project>
```

When I did that the connectionstring was "bar".
Granted: I use Nant 0.91 final.

Comment: Thanks, it worked with both 0.91 final and alpha. I'm sure I tried enclosing the property in a project tag, but I must've done something else wrong then.